# Bootstrap 3 Jumbotron Has Rounded Edges (How Do I Get Rid of Them?)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap 3, the .jumbotron has rounded edges (by default). Is there a way to get rid of the rounded edges? (Picture of rounded edges below for reference)

[image: .jumbotron rounded edges]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Bootstrap 3 Jumbotron has the class:

```
.container .jumbotron {
    border-radius: 6px ;
}
```

You will want to set that to border-radius: 0px;, but I would suggest adding that same class to a separate stylesheet (being called after bootstrap.css) and override it, rather than changing the bootstrap.css file directly.

```
.container .jumbotron {
    border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: I had to use `!important` for my style override.

Answer (score 8):

To get rid off rounded edges use .jumbotron-fluid along with .jumbotron and place a container within as described [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/jumbotron/)

```
 <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
   <div class="container">
    ...
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Actually, this solution works for BS 4 only. but +1 for mentioning

Answer (score 5):

Bootstrap suggests below [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron)

To make the jumbotron full width, and without rounded corners, place it outside all .containers and instead add a .container within.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is actually the most accurate solution for BS 3. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but you just have to add rounded-0 to get rid of it now with BS4 :

```
   <div class="jumbotron rounded-0>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done this already, make sure that the Jumbotron class is before your container.

EX.

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="container-fluid>
```